# In search of the mysterious skipped Jest test

Tags: jestjs

We have the following output at the end of our Jest test base:

```
Test Suites: 273 passed, 273 total
Tests:       1 skipped, 1923 passed, 1924 total
Snapshots:   61 passed, 61 total
Time:        38.885 s, estimated 39 s
```

You see there is one skipped test.

When I search my test files either for `it.skip` or `test.skip` or generally `skip` I find nothing.

What I also tried is outputting the test run into JSON via:

```
jest --json --outputFile=testrun.json
```

In the top of the file I find this information:

```json
{
  "numFailedTestSuites": 0,
  "numFailedTests": 0,
  "numPassedTestSuites": 273,
  "numPassedTests": 1923,
  "numPendingTestSuites": 0,
  "numPendingTests": 1,
  "numRuntimeErrorTestSuites": 0,
  "numTodoTests": 0,
  "numTotalTestSuites": 273,
  "numTotalTests": 1924,
  ...
}
```

so it looks like that `numPendingTests` is the one pointing to the skipped one. But when I search the output file, again, no trace of a skipped test. In fact, I did a search for `"status": "[a-z]`and there is no other status to be found than **passed**.

Short of looking through 270+ test suites, how else could a skipped test hide from me? Is there any way to find it?

Comment: Is it skipped using xtest/xit instead of .skip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by johnrsharp as a comment, another way to skip tests in Jest is to prefix the term `it`(`test`) with `x`- so if you want to scan the files for skipped tests, you also need to look out for `xit` or `xtest`.

Comment: Look for "only" as well, as all the other tests in the group will be marked as skipped

Answer (score 1):

The npm package "jest-skipped-reporter" can do this. As descibed in the package's readme, install the package, add the reporter to the jest config, and then run the tests. It provides the file name and title of any skipped tests.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-skipped-reporter